# The issue with using of Omit for generic type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

There is the minimum reproducible example:

```
interface BasicObject {
    name: string;
}

interface Object extends BasicObject {
    code: string
}

function generic<T extends BasicObject> (options: T) {
    // something
}

function externalGeneric<T extends BasicObject>(a: Omit<T, 'name'>) {
    generic(a);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM7AQeQEYBWECYyA3gFDLXIhwC2EAXMhmFKAOYDcFAvhQqhIsRCnxESyCAA9IIACYY0mbBOKlKNZAgD2C5q3Zd%20gmAFcQJYLpDJOEENGwAeACrS5jpSqy5CGgB8yAAUugAOYDYgGCxuAJTkVDQA9CmsuoxgABYmAhQWVlG2niJ0ADYA4o7OCO6l3srofuokgSFwLDj0wGDuADTIAOR0jEOBiVo0Dk4cCB3xvAJAA).

Could you explain, why Typescript ignores the fact that `a` doesn't have `name` field and therefore doesn't extend `BasicObject`?

The version of Typescript is 4.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you redeclare global `Object` interface, try change

```
interface Object extends BasicObject {
    code: string
}
```

To

```
interface SomeOtherNameThanObject extends BasicObject {
    code: string
}
```